# learn python the hard way exercise 25 print_first does not give same result as print_last

Tags: python

So in exercise 25 you the assignment is to make a script that breaks up a sentence and sort it or print the first/last word. there is then there is a function which does all sorting and print first and last word. Now mine does not print the last word. So checked my print_last_word(words) and it runs but it returns a word with '' so instead of wait i get 'wait' so i guess this messes up my print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence) but i can't see why.

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up words for us"""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    """sort the words"""
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(words):
    """Prints the first word after popping it off"""
    word = words.pop(0)
    print word

def print_last_word(words):
    """Prints the last word after popping it off"""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    return word

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words"""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    return sort_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """Prints the first and last words of the sentence"""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """Sorts the words then prints the first and last one"""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

results:

```
>>> import ex25b
>>> sentence = "All good things come to those who wait"
>>> words = ex25b.break_words(sentence)
>>> words
['All', 'good', 'things', 'come', 'to', 'those', 'who', 'wait']
>>> ex25b.print_first_word(words)
All
>>> ex25b.print_last_word(words)
'wait'
>>> ex25b.print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
All
>>>
```

Comment: For py2, `sort_words` is a longer way to write `sorted`, and not helpful.  For py3, `sorted` returns an iterator and the code, as is, will not work.  It could be made to work with py3 by copying the list and then sorting.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `print_first_word` function actually prints the word.  Your `print_last_word` function just returns the word (doesn't print it).  Just change your return to a print in this function.

Answer (score 0):

In addotion to the answer @Gerrat, your `print_last_word` and `print_first_word` actually change the input list. The pop operation takes one element of the list:

```
a=[1,2,3]
print_last_word(a)
print(a)
# a is [1, 2] # the 3 is gone. Pop removed it.
```

Not sure you are aware of this, but this is very dangerous behavior for a function that should just print the last element, instead of actually removing it form the list and printing it. It might be your intention to actually remove it, but then the name is quite misleading.

Comment: Absolutely agree (although his functions do have a doc string explicitly stating their behaviour).  I haven't read it, but maybe: `Learn Python the Hard Way` teaches from the school of hard knocks, where they show some poor practices that will come back to bite the reader later :)

Comment: Thank you Marcin, I read a comment from someone about this here on stack overflow. Think i'll try to rewrite this function without pop will be a good challenge i guess :)